# OpenCL 2.0 on AMD GPU

Tags: opencl, gpu, amd-app

I'm trying to initialize OpenCL 2.0 on AMD Fury X and I'm looking at the value of `__OPENCL_VERSION__`. It is 120 no matter what. I'm looking inside my driver and both `#define __OPENCL_VERSION__ 120` and `#define __OPENCL_VERSION__ 200` can be found there.

Does there need to be a special flag somewhere to enable version 2.0? I have the following platform and device:

> OpenCL platform 'AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing' by Advanced Micro Devices, Inc., version OpenCL 2.0 AMD-APP (1912.5), FULL_PROFILE
>   device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 'Fiji' (driver version: 1912.5 (VM))
>           OpenCL version: OpenCL 2.0 AMD-APP (1912.5)
>           OpenCL "C" version: OpenCL C 2.0

**EDIT**

Ah, silly. It seems to help to specify `-cl-std=CL2.0` in the compiler options in `clCreateProgramWithSource`. Is that supposed to be the expected behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is that supposed to be the expected behaviour?

Yes. Here's the relevant paragraph from the OpenCL 2.0 specification (section **5.8.4.5 Options Controlling the OpenCL C version**):

> If the –cl-std build option is not specified, the highest OpenCL C 1.x language version supported by each device is used when compiling the program for each device. Applications are required to specify the –cl-std=CL2.0 option if they want to compile or build their programs with OpenCL C 2.0.

Comment: Should have googled harder. I have another problem, when compiled this way and saving the binary, the `clCreateProgramWithBinary()` crashes the application (some access violation inside the call). Do you happen to have any experience with that? Works well without `-cl-std=CL2.0`.

Comment: No personal experience, but any crash like that sounds like a bug to me. Best raise a bug with AMD directly for that.